# How to create a custom react hook?

Tags: reactjs

I have an `addQuery` function that sets the `url` with query parameters, like `/hello/?page=1&role=admin` etc. I want to use that `function` into multiple files for updating the URL and duplicating that `function` does not make sense.

```js
export default function Hello() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const history = useHistory();

  const addQuery = (key, value) => {
    let pathname = location.pathname;
    let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    searchParams.set(key, value);
    history.push({
      pathname: pathname,
      search: searchParams.toString()
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>hello world</h1>
      <button onClick={() => addQuery("page", 1)}>page 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => addQuery("page", 2)}>page 2</button>
      <button onClick={() => addQuery("user_role", "admin")}>Admin role</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Is there a way to extract the logic into a separate hook?

Here is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/add-query-hook-js2k7?file=/src/home.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract the `addQuery` function to a separate hook you have to return the desired function from the hook and call it when required.

Solution, in useAddQuery.js

```
import { useLocation, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { useCallback } from "react";

export function useAddQuery() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const history = useHistory();

  const addQuery = useCallback(
    (key, value) => {
      let pathname = location.pathname;
      let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
      searchParams.set(key, value);
      history.push({
        pathname: pathname,
        search: searchParams.toString()
      });
    },
    [location, history]
  );

  return addQuery;
}
```

Working codesandbox example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/add-query-hook-cqy1j?file=/src/useAddQuery.js:0-546)

Comment: Thanks a ton. Hey, why did you use the ```useCallback``` hook?

Comment: `useCallback` is used to memoize the callback so it does not cause unnecessary re-renders the callback is passed as a prop to other components. Since you said you want to to use the custom hook in multiple components, I assumed that maybe in some component you need to pass it as a prop. Hence it's better to memoize it. Learn more about `useCallback` here [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

Comment: You can make another possible optimization in the custom `useAddQuery` hook so that when you make use of the custom hook you can directly call the `addQuery` function instead of making another function like `() => addQuery("page", 1)`. See the example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/add-query-hook-cqy1j?file=/src/useAddQuery.js)